# Using Amazon EC2 as a proxy for PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to Amazon Web Services/EC2.  Would it be possible to setup a private proxy that I could connect to through PHP cURL?

An important caveat is that it should be possible to access from a shared host which I don't have physical access to.. The solutions I've seen elsewhere seem to require that you use a specific local machine to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you setup Squid on the EC2 server and restrict it by username and password AND/OR IP address it would be just fine. As long as your second server (even shared host) has PHP cURL support you should be fine, as you can define username and password you want to use to access the proxy server while making a curl request. You can use the IP of the shared box to secure your proxy server, so that other people don't start abusing it.